# Why worker threads aren't working when creating an class instance from other file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-worker-threads

I have this typescript file:

```
import { Worker, WorkerOptions, isMainThread, parentPort } from "worker_threads";
import path from "path";

export class SimpleWorker {
    private worker: any;

    constructor() {
        if (isMainThread) {
            console.log('Resolved Path:', path.join(__filename));

            const resolvedPath = path.join(__filename)

            this.worker = this.worker = new Worker(resolvedPath, {
                execArgv: /\.ts$/.test(resolvedPath) ? ["--require", "ts-node/register"] : undefined,
            });

            this.worker.on('message', (message: any) => {
                console.log(message);
            });

            this.worker.on('error', (error: any) => {
                console.log('Error from worker:', error);
            });

            this.worker.on('exit', (code: any) => {
                console.log('Worker has exited:', code);
            });

        } else {
            parentPort.postMessage('Hello from worker thread');
        }
    }
}

const simpleWorker = new SimpleWorker();
```

When executing the file using: `npx ts-node examples/simple_worker.ts` It will print:

```
Resolved Path: /home/user1/code/playground/examples/simple_worker.ts
Hello from worker thread
Worker has exited: 0
```

Now, when I remove the line `const simpleWorker = new SimpleWorker();` from `simple_worker.ts` file.

And create another file called "test_worker.ts"

```
import { SimpleWorker } from './simple_worker';

const main = new SimpleWorker();
```

When executing this file using: `npx ts-node examples/test_worker.ts` It will print:

```
Resolved Path: /home/user1/code/playground/examples/simple_worker.ts
Worker has exited: 0
```

The threading didn't work.. why?

Comment: Uh, if you remove that line, then of course the `else { parentPort.postMessage('Hello from worker thread'); }` in the `new SimpleWorker` constructor won't be executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in the first approach, The `simple_worker.ts` creates an instance. So when you register the worker using `simple_worker.ts`, the following things happen.

**Creates Instance** -> **constructor runs** -> **Goes to else part** -> **posts message**

**But** in the second approach, You have removed the `const simpleWorker = new SimpleWorker();`part. So when you register the worker using `simple_worker.ts`, No instance will be created, `constructor` won't run.

#### How to fix?

It depends on your usage and requirements, But the simplest way is to pass the file (which init the instance ) as an argument.

```
export class SimpleWorker {
    private worker: any;

    constructor( filepath: string ) {
        if (isMainThread) {
            console.log('Resolved Path:', path.join(filepath));

            const resolvedPath = path.join(filepath)
            // rest of your code

        } else {
            parentPort.postMessage('Hello from worker thread');
        }
    }
}
```

then,

```
import { SimpleWorker } from './simple_worker';

// Passing this file as arg, coz here only we creates the instance
const main = new SimpleWorker(__filename);
```

Comment: I am confused, in the second approach, I AM creating an instance from SimpleWorker using `new SimpleWorker();` how come constructor will not run?  I can see the `Resolved Path` gets printed from constructor !

Comment: In your second approach, the resolved file is, `Resolved Path: /home/user1/code/playground/examples/simple_worker.ts` But you create an instance in `test_worker.ts` only. Since `simple_worker.ts` has just the class. it won't actually create anything